# Ubuntu 14.0.4 apt-get update fails for any installs and upgrades in trusty

Tags: command-line, apt, ppa, software-sources

I have tried various recommendations from the web to no success.
The `apt-get update` gives errors .
Here are my error messages after `sudo apt-get udpate`:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have reviewed and tried the existing stackexchange answers that are not working for me.
Trying to cleanup the ppa as per advice in sourcse gives me the following errors :
 For example, the following command to remove the ppa shows other scary messages :

```
winsella@winsella:~$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppaname-ppa-$(lsb_release -sc).list*
[sudo] password for winsella:
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
Failed to open /var/lib/samba/private/secrets.tdb
tdbsam_open: Failed to open/create TDB passwd [/var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb]
tdbsam_getsampwnam: failed to open /var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb!
tdbsam_open: Failed to open/create TDB passwd [/var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb]
tdbsam_getsampwnam: failed to open /var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb!
tdbsam_open: Failed to open/create TDB passwd [/var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb]
tdbsam_new_rid: failed to open /var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb!
rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppaname-ppa-trusty.list*’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for the quick responses, at this time I am just worried about the state of apt-get update. I have replaced my existing sourcse.list with the new list generated from   Ubuntu Sources List Generator site, and the apt-get now shows the following error :   W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: You should use the graphical method described in the first section of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/92897/44179)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking specifically for the Oracle 7 java?  If so, you may have better luck with the answer given by @user283885.  Webupd8 also has an Oracle 8 java installer at [this link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html).

If however, you just want easy to maintain, java runtimes, you should consider removing the PPS from software sources, and using the Ubuntu Software Center to load OpenJDK, either in version 6 or version 7

Comment: Thank you, I need JDK (with javac, not just runtime), but my issue is the apt-get update, have been trying various approaches to fix my sources first without success.

Comment: You gots lotsa fixins to do - upubuntu.com does not support trusty, which is why those two PPAs are failing.

Comment: Thanks Charles, any alternatives or pointers you can give me how I can get around the issue that ubuntu.com does not support trusty ?

Comment: Its not Ubuntu, its a separate package you installed from someplace called UpUbuntu.  You question now points to a duplicate, which I just read through this morning.  Great set of answers, tips and pointers in there.